# Drop voltage a bit

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, resistors, diodes, step-down

I have this ATtiny13a mcu led setup that uses total of 33mA when both leds are on and it works perfectly when powered through usb output.

My problem is that now I want to power it using a 6V 500mA wall adapter, so I want to drop the 6V to below 5.5V since ATtiny13a mcu works at 1.8-5.5 Volts range.

I have come up with two different circuits to achieve this small voltage drop.
Please advice which one of these circuit is better. If both are not good then do tell me other options.

1. Use a 1N4007 diode in series with Vcc.
   [image]
2. Use a small 33 ohm resistor in series with Vcc.
   [image]

I checked the wall adapter with a multimeter and it outputs 5.89 volts when no load is connected.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use a regulator?

Comment: Yes, because I don't have any at hand.

Comment: I suppose it's a bit late for this project, but I recommend you keep some of both TO-220 and TO-92 versions of 5V and 3.3V regulators on hand.

Comment: Point taken, I'll buy a few AMS1117 to use on future projects.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you should start using the ground symbol to make the schematic more tidy.

Comment: Note that you can embed the CircuitLab schematics directly into your posts. You don't need to take a screen-grab. It also means that you can edit, copy, paste, etc. between questions and answers.

Comment: @pipe I'll keep that in mind next time I post a circuit

Comment: @Transistor  I didn't know that. thanks for the info

Comment: When in doubt... *add more diodes.* I've even seen a pair of diodes and a light globe used to make a rudimentary constant-ish current battery charger so anything's possible. You could even ditch the extra LED (D1) in the circuit **Transistor** suggested  and just have a higher value resistor straight from the end of the diode string to ground if you were short on LEDs, not very efficient, but it works.

Comment: Ok, I see, anyways I added the led and it works now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Neither is good because the voltage drop is current dependent. If the LEDs are off (such as at power-up) the voltage drop will be minimal. In addition, your target voltage is the absolute max of the micro and this is not a good place to be!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbErqp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Loading the diode voltage dropper.*

If you want to proceed with this approach I suggest that you put a minimum load on the diode dropper and get the voltage well into the safe operating voltage range of the micro. A fixed resistor pulling a few tens of mA should suffice and you could make use of it to light a "power-on" LED.

The power waste will be insignificant on a mains power supply.

---

Problems with the resistor option:

- Let's say you're aiming for a 5 V supply and that the LED resistors drop 3 V. We can calculate the LED current then as \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {3}{220} = 13.5 \mathrm {mA} \$.
- Let's also assume that the micro draws 0.5 mA. (Wild guess.)
- There are three possible conditions: no LED, one LED and two LEDs. Let's look at the voltage drop through your 33 Ω resistor in each case.

*Table 1. Resistor voltage drop calculations.*

```
               I         V drop
No LED         0.5 mA    0.5 x 33  = 16.5 mV
 1 LED         14 mA     14 x 33   = 462 mV
 2 LEDs        27.5 mA   27.5 x 33 = 907 mV
```

This clearly shows that there is no regulation with the resistor (meaning that the voltage varies with load) and that on power-up or with all LEDs off that the voltage on the micro will be only 16.5 mV below the supply.

Comment: I like the "power-on" status led idea very much when using diode dropper setup. If possible can you please tell me about the resistor dropper circuit's drawback.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: I like the little `t`! I use to draw an outline but that small symbol is less jarring.

Comment: I've been using it to get CircuitLab to size my schematics appropriately for a couple of years. It avoids the "circuits for the deaf" appearance when there are only a couple of components. You are the first to comment! Oddly enough it also helps me quickly recognise my own schematics when I revisit an old post.

Comment: Perfectly Explained. Thank you so much. I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: Let's say if I were to use L7805, what electrolytic capacitor value would you suggest for input and output. Would a 10uF input and a 1uF output do the job?

Comment: The 7805 needs a couple of volts higher on the input - typically about 7 V in for 5 V out. It's not suitable for your application. It's worth a look at the datasheet to see how to figure this out from the specifications.

Comment: Ok, I understand.